# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null when trying to lazy load script

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, lazy-loading

I am trying to get angularjs to lazy load script files found in a ng-include but no matter what i do i can get pass this error. The error as far as i can tell is caused by chrome from a script call filters.js

```
(function (ng) {
'use strict';

var app = ng.module('ngLoadScript', []);

app.directive('script', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            if (attr.type=='text/javascript-lazy') {
                var code = elem.text();
                eval(code);
                //var f = new Function(code);
                //f();
            }
        }
    };
});
}(angular));
```

the commented out lines are the original the eval(code) was just to see if it would make a difference.

i have tried the jquery solution but i got the same problem and one got any ideas?

Comment: so something in the `code` is null? Perhaps a `try {} catch() {}` ? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp